# Add sample button creating 'Uncaught exception' error

Tags: magento-1.8, product, php

I have found a script that adds a 'sample request' button that should allow me to add a sample of every product, I'm getting an error when I click the sample request button.

This is the error I get:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message
>   'Image does not exist.' in
>   /var/www/vhosts/webcontrolcentre.co.uk/httpdocs/perfume/app/Mage.php:595
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/vhosts/webcontrolcentre.co.uk/httpdocs/perfume/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend/Media.php(274):
>   Mage::throwException('Image does not ...') #1
>   /var/www/vhosts/webcontrolcentre.co.uk/httpdocs/perfume/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php(1047):
>   Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Media->addImage(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), '/var/www/vhosts...', Array, false, false) #2
>   /var/www/vhosts/webcontrolcentre.co.uk/httpdocs/perfume/getSample.php(82):
>   Mage_Catalog_Model_Product->addImageToMediaGallery('/var/www/vhosts...',
>   Array, false, false) #3 {main} thrown in
>   /var/www/vhosts/webcontrolcentre.co.uk/httpdocs/perfume/app/Mage.php
>   on line 595

The script that allows the sample to be created is in a file called getSample.php and it includes:

```
<?php

 ini_set('display_errors', 1);
 error_reporting(E_ALL);

 //print_r($_POST);

 require_once 'app/Mage.php';
 Mage::app();



 Mage::getSingleton("core/session", array("name" => "frontend"));
 Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setSampleError("");
 // Store users session
 $session = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session");

 //Store cart items
 $totalNumOfCartItem = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getItemsQty();

 //Store cart items
 $theitems = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getItems();

 $thecount = 0;

 foreach($theitems as $ti){

 $thename = $ti['name'];

 $test = strpos($thename,'Free Sample');

 if($test !== false){
 $thecount = $thecount+1;
 }

 }

 if(isset($_POST['name'])){
 $name = $_POST['name'];

 $id = $_POST['id'];
 if(isset($_POST['simpleid']) && !empty($_POST['simpleid'])){
 $simpleid = $_POST['simpleid'];
 }
 }
 if(isset($_GET['name'])){
 $name = $_GET['name'];
 if(isset($_GET['simpleid']) && !empty($_GET['simpleid'])){
 $simpleid = $_GET['simpleid'];
 }
 $id = $_GET['id'];
 }

 // retrict shopping cart to only allow 5 samples
 if ($totalNumOfCartItem <= 4)
 {
 $theproduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);

 if($simpleid){
 $thesimple = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($simpleid);
 }

 if($thecount < 2)
 {
 // instatiate Product
 $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
 if($simpleid){
 $product->setSku($thesimple->getSku()."*".rand());
 } else {
 $product->setSku($theproduct->getSku()."*".rand());
 }
 $product->setName("Sample of ".$name);
 // $product->setDescription("Sample of ".$name);
 $product->setShortDescription($name." – Sample");
 $product->setPrice(0.00);
 $product->setTypeId('simple');

 $product->setImageUrl($theproduct->getImageUrl()); // set the images from the original product
 $product->setThumbnailUrl($theproduct->getImageUrl());
 $product->setImage($theproduct->getSmallImage());
 $product->setMediaGallery (array('images'=>array (), 'values'=>array ()));
 $product->addImageToMediaGallery($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/media/catalog/product".$theproduct->getSmallImage(), array('image','small_image','thumbnail'), false, false);
 $product->setAttributeSetId(9); // need to look this up
 $product->setCategoryIds("15"); // need to look these up
 $product->setWeight(21212121.21);
 $product->setTaxClassId(2); // taxable goods
 $product->setVisibility(1); // catalog, search
 $product->setStatus(1); // enabled
 // assign product to the default website
 $product->setWebsiteIds(array(Mage::app()->getStore(true)->getWebsite()->getId()));


 // get product’s general info such price, status, description

 $stockData = $product->getStockData();

 // update stock data using new data
 $stockData['qty'] = 1;
 $stockData['is_in_stock'] = 1;
 $stockData['manage_stock'] = 1;
 $stockData['max_sale_qty'] = 5;

 // then set product’s stock data to update
 $product->setStockData($stockData);
 //die();

 // call save() method to save your product with updated data
 $product->save();


 header("Location: /checkout/cart/add/product/".$product->getId()."/");
 }
 }

 else
 {
 Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError("You are only allowed a maximum of 5 sample products");

 header("Location: /checkout/cart");
 }
 ?>
```

I'm hoping someone can help as I really would like an 'add sample' button but cannot find a solution anywhere so I'm hoping I can get this script to work.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would better use `Mage::getBaseDir('media')` instead of `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/media` in your addImage function. If things remain the same, try check what is the path to the image and if the image exists there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this maybe a stupid question but how would I use the Mage::getbaseDir('media') in this line of code?$product->addImageToMediaGallery($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/media/catalog/product".$theproduct->getSmallImage(), array('image','small_image','thumbnail'), false, false); I've tried a couple of ways but still getting the error and the image does exist in that file directory.

Comment: you replace $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/media by Mage::getBaseDir('media')."

Comment: I have done that and now I get a different error which is a Uncaught exception 'PDOException, so I think your solution has fixed the first error, thankyou for your help.

Comment: can you tick as resolved ?